# Is A Plural Verb Indicative on Singular or Plural When Modifying Elokim

Tags: grammar-dikduk, rashi, parashat-ki-tisa

Rashi on Shemot 32:1 says bnei Yisrael desired many gods (ד״ה ״אשר ילכו לפנינו״) because as Be’er Mayim Chaim points out, the verse uses the plural verb ילכו instead of ילך.  There really should be no problem with the plural anyways since the Hebrew Elokim is plural and can have verbs and modifying words in the plural as well.  To prove this, in Bereishit 20:13 ד״ה כאשר התעו Rashi gives a thorough explanation of how Elokim can take verbs in the plural.  This wouldn’t require Rashi to find a solution as it is grammatically correct on a pshat level.

How then can Rashi prove that they wanted many gods if he himself in Bereishit stated that it is normal and grammatically acceptable to have plural verbs for Elokim?  Why doesn’t Rashi accept that maybe it was only one G-d they wanted?

Comment: I think it's from אלה

Comment: Isn't it because it is corroborated by the plural in 32:8?